# Xamarin.Android Designer shows controls differently as they appear on my phone

Tags: c#, android, .net, xml, xamarin

I am unable to setup Xamarin.Android Designer pretty well. In my previous version of Windows and Visual Studio the Xamarin Default designer view looked Fine, but after upgrading to *VS2015* and *Win10*, My Designer doesn't seem to be very well, As it's controls show differently on the designer and differently on my mobile phone. I am sharing two pictures of how it looks like on my phone and how it looks on Xamarin Designer.

In my Xamarin Designer:
[image: Xamarin Designer]

In my Mobile Phone:
[image: Mobile phone view]

Please assist me regarding this issue, Thank you!
**EDIT**:
you won't be able to see the controls until you change their color if I choose the default theme of the designer.

Here it is how it looks when the default theme is selected
[image: Default Theme]

**EDIT**:
=> Here is my Main.axml file code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:weightSum="100"
      android:minWidth="25px"
      android:minHeight="25px"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
    android:text="Create An Account"
    android:id="@+id/tvCreateAccount"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:textColor="#368DEB"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSignin"
    android:text="Sign in"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:background="@drawable/btnSignInStyle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
<TextView
    android:text="Or"
    android:id="@+id/tvOr"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSignup"
    android:text="Sign Up with Email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="35"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
         <ProgressBar
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
             android:indeterminate="true"
             android:id="@+id/progressBar1" />
     </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

=> Here is the xml File that I am assigning to *btnSignin*

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="false">
     <layer-list>
       <item android:right="2dp" android:top="5dp">
         <shape>
           <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
           <solid android:color="#D6D6D6"/>
         </shape>
       </item>

       <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
         <shape>
           <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#4A6EA9" android:startColor="#4A6EA9"/>
           <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#BABABA"/>
           <corners android:radius="4dp"/> 
           <padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp"/>
         </shape>
       </item>
     </layer-list>
   </item>
   <item android:state_pressed="true">
     <layer-list>
       <item android:right="2dp" android:top="5dp">
         <shape>
           <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
           <solid android:color="#D6D6D6"/>
         </shape>
       </item>
       <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
         <shape>
           <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
           <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#7C97C1" android:startColor="#4A6EA9"/>
           <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#BABABA"/>
           <padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp"/>
         </shape>
       </item>
     </layer-list>
   </item>
 </selector>
```

Comment: What type of device is your physical phone?

Comment: It's an android phone, the UI seems perfectly fine on it but the designer is not populating the UI properly,

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, and by using default theme, the theme is @android:style/Theme.Material - Dark theme, the background should be dark gray/black. Only when I change the theme to Default Theme Light, the background is like in your picture - white. And under both themes, I cannot reproduce your issue. Have you tried to restart your VS or tried to create a new blank app to have a check?

Comment: Yes I have restarted the VS but that was not helpful for me, I am thinking to re-install the Visual Studio or Xamarin. But I was not willing to re-install the components! @GraceFeng-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing all sort of work arounds I finally Solved my Problem. What I did was downloaded the latest community version of Visual Studio 2015, and the Default Xamarin packages that were pre-installed in Visual Studio were not good for the health of my system. I just visited the Xamarin Site and downloaded the Xamarin components from there. and It installed other features plus the new Xamarin for VS2015, And now working it's fine on Xamarin Studio and on Visual Studio also!

[image: After Updating]